# v-model not working with <component> in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Why isn't v-model binding to my input in the example below? Is there a limitation of `<component>`?

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const config = ref({
  headers: [
    { field: 'id', label: 'Id', component: { type: 'input' } }, 
    { field: 'name', label: 'Name', component: { type: 'input' }  },
    // more configs for radio buttons and other custom components
  ],
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
  ]
})
</script>

<template>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="header in config.headers">
        <b>{{ header.label }}</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in config.data">
      <td v-for="header in config.headers">
        <component :is="header.component.type" v-model="item[header.field]" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {{ config.data }}
</template>
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `component :is="header.component.type"` with `input`?

Comment: @EstusFlask did a small update to the question to clarify that I don't want it limited to input fields.

Comment: How does your "component" looks like? What is the current behavior you get vs. what do you expect? currently we can not exclude your mounted component to not working properly. Also the comment above from Estus Flasks was intedent to ensure that your idea/use of v-model is working in the first place

Comment: @tjarbo The idea is to be able to do a `<component :is="header.component.type" v-model="item[header.field]" v-bind="header.component.props" />` that works for both native elements and my custom components. I understand that my custom components needs to implement v-model, but I was expecting it to work out of the box for vanilla elements like <input>

Comment: Looks like you'll have to desugar v-model to handle possible variations in header.component.type with v-if

Comment: This case is very interesting. I will investigate it further.

Comment: Here is the Vue GitHub Issue: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4428#issuecomment-1075329007. It will be fixed someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue `v-model` does work well for native elements.

But it obviously fails to work together with `<component :is`

Your code generates

```
<input modelvalue="foo">
```

The very quick workaround is to implement the binding of `value` directly.

```
:value="item[header.field]" @input="item[header.field] = $event.target.value"
```

But then you will need to update your components accordingly, to work with `value` instead of `modelValue`.

**UPDATE**

The workaround using `v-model:value` does work only in one way, same as `:value`.

```
<component :is="header.component.type" v-model:value="item[header.field]" />
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const config = ref({
  headers: [
    { field: 'id', label: 'Id', component: { type: 'input' } }, 
    { field: 'name', label: 'Name', component: { type: 'input' }  },
    // more configs for radio buttons and other custom components
  ],
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
  ]
})

const App = {
  setup() {
    return { config, test: 1 }  
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="header in config.headers">
        <b>{{ header.label }}</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in config.data">
      <td v-for="header in config.headers">
        <component :is="header.component.type" :value="item[header.field]" @input="item[header.field] = $event.target.value" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {{ config.data }}
  <hr/>
  v-model test: <input v-model="test" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Right, so I guess the most robust way would be to wrap all components, including native ones, in a shell that implements a unified v-model? E.g. `:modelValue="item[header.field]"`  and force the components to implement/emit `@update:modelValue`?

Comment: I would possibly do so.